# Linearlayout display only last data in android

Tags: android

i want to integrate horizonal scrollview with custom linear layout inflater so i set below code

```
for (int i=0;i<mArrayListPersonDataLists.size();i++)
{
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_pager_layout, null);
    TextView mTextView1=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_name);
    TextView mTextView2=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_email);
    TextView mTextView3=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_gender);
    mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
    mTextView1.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getName());
    mTextView2.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getEmail());
    mTextView3.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getGender());
    mLinearLayout.addView(child);
}
```

in above my array list include 9 data but in screen it is display only one data so any idea how  can i solve this ?

Comment: mLinearLayout.removeAllViews(); remove this line and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one...

```
for (int i=0;i<mArrayListPersonDataLists.size();i++)
 {
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_pager_layout, null);
TextView mTextView1=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_name);
TextView mTextView2=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_email);
TextView mTextView3=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_gender);
mTextView1.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getName());
mTextView2.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getEmail());
mTextView3.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getGender());
mLinearLayout.addView(child);
child.setId(i+1)
child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    //your code here  
                     int position=child.getId()-1;
                    Toast.makeText(HorizontalAcivity.this, mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    
                    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Ya but how can i write particulate position wise value inside child click ?

Comment: you can the get position when you click the view(i.e child).so that with in onClicklistener make an condition to check which position is being triggered  and do actions..

Comment: i try this code int pos=child.getId();
                            Toast.makeText(HorizontalAcivity.this, mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(pos).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); but it give me error like indexoutofbound

Comment: try this inside child onclicklistener..  Toast.makeText(HorizontalAcivity.this, mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: NO it is not working because when i put this code it give me error like make i final so when i make i final so in for loop syntax error comes

Comment: oh.....sorry i forgot...try to set child id as  index value. like child.setId(i); then   within onclicklistener try this... int pos=child.getId(); Toast.makeText(HorizontalAcivity.this, mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(pos).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: i thought it doesn't accept viewid as 0.so increment it with 1.and decrement it when you check on onClicklistener..

Comment: Can you post your code what you say i m not getting?

Answer (score 2):

You should write this function like this

```
mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
for (int i=0;i<mArrayListPersonDataLists.size();i++)
{
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_pager_layout, null);
    TextView mTextView1=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_name);
    TextView mTextView2=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_email);
    TextView mTextView3=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_gender);
    mTextView1.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getName());
    mTextView2.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getEmail());
    mTextView3.setText(mArrayListPersonDataLists.get(i).getGender());
    mLinearLayout.addView(child);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is also right so i give you 1 vote for that

Answer (score 1):

Remove a line with `mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();` :)

Comment: Ya it is working!! but how can i get item click for particulate item?

Comment: You should use ListView instead of ScrollView. Then you can use ```ListView.setOnItemClickListener()```

Comment: Your answer is also right so i give you 1 vote for that